# JAVA ERROR: can be replaced with multi-catch or several catch clauses catching specific exceptions

Tags: java, netbeans

private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
if(checkInputs() && imgPath != null){
try {
Connection con = getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO animal_information(animal_breed,animal_age,animal_found,animal_hairColor,"
                    + "animal_eyeColor,animal_specialTrait,animal_codeNumber,animal_image)"
                    + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

//ps.setString(1, pawsId.getText());
ps.setString(1, pawsBreed.getText());
ps.setString(2, pawsAge.getText());

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String addDate = dateFormat.format(pawsDate.getDate());
ps.setString(3, addDate);
ps.setString(4, pawsHairColor.getText());
ps.setString(5, pawsEyeColor.getText());
ps.setString(6, pawsUniqueTrait.getText());

InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(imgPath));
ps.setBlob(7, img);
ps.executeUpdate();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserted Data Successfully");   
} catch (Exception ex) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
}
}
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or More Fields Are Empty");
}
System.out.println("Breed => "+ pawsBreed.getText());
System.out.println("Age => "+ pawsAge.getText());
System.out.println("Hair Color => "+ pawsHairColor.getText());
System.out.println("Eye Color => "+ pawsEyeColor.getText());
System.out.println("Unique Traits => "+ pawsUniqueTrait.getText());
System.out.println("Image => "+ imgPath);
}
```

Hello Guys! I'm just a student and totally beginner learning java. I have encountered this problem "can be replaced with multi-catch or several catch clauses catching  specific exceptions" in the image at the part catch (Exception ex) it has yellow underline color and thats giving me an error. I want to insert data into my database but it doesnt insert because of this error. As can you see in my code I have tried printing the data out and it was all successful. can someone please enlighten and help me what did I do wrong. please...

Comment: Post text; code is text. Don't make people go look at images. In any case, catching all exceptions at once is generally considered a bad practice. It's not an error, just a bad idea.

Comment: Could you add the code in the post and not like img?

Comment: Sorry about the image, I have edited it now and the code has been posted.

Comment: The yellow underlined text in Netbeans isn't an error.

Comment: Also, this isn't why the data isn't inserted into your database. That must be caused elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The yellow line is not an error, but a warning or suggestion.

What it's suggesting is that your `catch (Exception e)` is over-broad: it would apply to far more types of exception than just the ones that could be thrown.

Someone may introduce new code that throws a different type of exception, and they may not expect your `catch` to handle it. So, best practice is to only handle exceptions that are possible.

What you should do is replace that line with `catch (SQLException e)`. Often, clicking on the yellow icon accompanying the warning will give you an option to have the editor do this for you.

I think from your code there is only one checked exception throwable from the `try` clause, that being `SQLException`, but if there were more than one, you could use multi-catch to handle all possiblities with the same code:

```
 try {
     ...
 }
 catch (FooException | BarException e) {
     ... handle both types of exception with the same code
 }
```

or you could have multiple `catch` clauses if you need to handle different exceptions in different ways:

```
 try {
     ...
 }
 catch (FooException e) {
     ... handle FooException one way
 }
 catch (BarException e) {
     ... handle BarException differently
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight sir.

Comment: How can I suppress this warning?

Comment: It depends on your IDE. In NetBeans, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Hints -> JDK Migration Support, and there you can untick "Use specific catch"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the yellow line isn't an error.

Exception class is parent class of all of sub(child) exception classes which are IOException, ClassNotFoundException vs..

```
try{

...

}catch(Exception e){

}
```

This catch block catches all of subclasses exceptions including IOException, ClassNotFoundException vs.. For example if your try block throws an SQLException, catch block will catch this exception. Or if your try block throws an FileNotFoundException, catch block will catch this exception too. That is your catch block is not be specialized for spesific exceptions.

```
try{

...

}catch(FileNotFoundException e){

}
```

As for this catch block catches only FileNotFoundException exceptions.

The yellow line in netbeans explains that you can specialize your catch block for spesific exception.